# Plot date and time (x axis) versus a value (y axis) using data from txt file (Python) (columns separated only by spaces)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to plot date and time(x-axis) versus a value (y-axis) from text file. I found a code on this website that is so clouse on the code that I need,
but the problem is that it read a text file where the third column is separated by comma.
In may case I have only space, and I don't know how split the third columns from the previous

the code is this :

```
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
x = []
y = []
t = []
fig = plt.figure()

readFile = open('1.txt', 'r')
sepFile = readFile.read().split('\n')
readFile.close()
for idx, plotPair in enumerate(sepFile):
    if plotPair in '. ':

        continue
    if idx > 1:  
        xAndY = plotPair.split(',')
        time_string = xAndY[0]
        time_string1 = datetime.strptime(time_string, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
        t.append(time_string1)
        y.append(float(xAndY[1]))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, axisbg='white')
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'))
ax1.plot(t, y, 'r-', linewidth=3.3)
plt.title('Subordinate prediction')
plt.xlabel('DATA/TIME')
plt.ylabel('Height (Meters relative to MLLW)')
fig.autofmt_xdate(rotation=45)
fig.tight_layout()
fig.show()
```

and my text file is this:

```
01/12/2014  4:36    1.6
01/12/2014  10:20   0.45
01/12/2014  16:50   2
01/12/2014  23:28   0.21
02/12/2014  5:52    1.54
02/12/2014  11:11   0.48
02/12/2014  17:40   2.14
03/12/2014  0:28    0.04
03/12/2014  6:54    1.51
03/12/2014  11:58   0.48
03/12/2014  18:26   2.25
04/12/2014  1:20    -0.09
04/12/2014  7:46    1.48
04/12/2014  12:43   0.46
04/12/2014  19:09   2.32
05/12/2014  2:08    -0.17
05/12/2014  8:32    1.44
05/12/2014  13:27   0.44
```

it doesn't work, please some one can help me?

Comment: Can you split by  \t?

Answer (score 0):

I would say the most likely approach would be something along the lines of:

```
    ...
    xAndY = plotPair.split('\t')
    time_string = xAndY[0]+" "+xAndY[1]
    time_string1 = datetime.strptime(time_string, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
    t.append(time_string1)
    y.append(float(xAndY[2]))
    ...
```

This splits by the apparent Tab Character in your file(going by what is posted) and then takes, from the resulting array containing 3 values, the first two parts and combines them for the datetime and the last part is the y value.

### Edit:

You have forgotten to indent properly.  All the code I gave you should be aligned under the if statement like so:

```
     if idx > 1:  
        xAndY = plotPair.split('\t')
        time_string = xAndY[0]+" "+xAndY[1]
        time_string1 = datetime.strptime(time_string, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
        t.append(time_string1)
        y.append(float(xAndY[2]))
```

Don't forget that in python the white space is important.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I add the part of code that you suggested me, but I have still this error ;(

Comment: ella\fo\dataTime.py", line 19, in <module>
    time_string = xAndY[0]+" "+xAndY[1]
NameError: name 'xAndY' is not defined

Comment: How can I figure out?